# Python: strings - how to find the position of the nearest string that comes before and after another string

Tags: python, string

I have this text in a string:

> Harry Potter is a series of fantasy novels written by British author J. K. Rowling. The novels chronicle the life of a young wizard, Harry Potter, and his friends Hermione Granger and Ron Weasley, all of whom are students at Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry. The main story arc concerns Harry's struggle against Lord Voldemort, a dark wizard who intends to become immortal, overthrow the wizard governing body known as the Ministry of Magic, and subjugate all wizards and Muggles. Since the release of the first novel, Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, on 26 June 1997, the books have found immense popularity, critical acclaim and commercial success worldwide. The series has now been translated into multiple languages including Irish, Spanish, French, German and Swedish to name a few. They have attracted a wide adult audience as well as younger readers, and are often considered cornerstones of modern young adult literature.[3] The series has also had its share of criticism, including concern

I need to create a new string that goes from the first "Harry Potter" that comes before "books" and the first "multiple" that comes after "books"

I'm trying to go this way:

**a) Find if there is "books" in the string and where it is**

No problem here...

```
books_position = string.find("books")
```

**b) Find the nearest "Harry Potter" that comes before "books"**

No idea how to do that...

**c) Find the nearest "multiple" that comes after "books"**

Same as above

**d) Create a new string with the text between "Harry Potter" and "multiple"**

Once I have the right position of "Harry Potter" and "multiple" it might be quite easy

```
new_string=string[position_harry_potter:position_multiple]
```

So, my problem is on letter b and c. How to find the nearest "Harry Potter" that comes before books and how to find the nearest "multiple" that comes after "books"?

Can someone help?

Comment: You can tell find where to start and finish searching. it's right in the docs. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find their positions as `string.rfind('Harry Potter', 0, books_position)` and `string.find('multiple', books_position)` respectively.

The first code will get the "Harry Potter" that stands the nearest to "books". The second one will get the first "multiple" that comes after "books"

Comment: BTW: there are 3 `'Harry Potter'` before `books_position` - you can use `rfind()` to find the last one - the nearest to `books_position`.

Comment: it depends what means "first before" - for some people it may means the nearest one.

Comment: I mean the nearest! Thanks for pointing it out, I will correct the question

Comment: Tried the solution and actually it works fine to find the nearest string before, but to find the nearest string after it doesn't work... it finds the farthest one

Comment: `find` returns the lowest index; see https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.find. Perhaps you used `rfind` for both of them? As a side note, in your example there is only a single occurrence of "multiple", so in that case, the first occurrence is also the last.

Comment: `find` will always give the first one. Another possible issue could be casing as `find` is case sensitive?

Comment: actually, I've noticed that the above info I gave is wrong, actually the problem is that it is finding the first "Harry Potter" in the text (not the nearest) and the first "multiple" after "books". So, the problem is in "Harry Potter" not in "multiple"

Comment: Ohhh, I found out how to fix it. Thanks for showing the way. I will fix your post and accept the answer